# Проблема с редиректом с http на https через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

На самописном движке возникла задача перейти на https. Что бы не потерять в поиске пытаюсь настраивать редирект в htaccess
Пытался сделать двумя вариантами, но результат один:
Если заходить сразу по https то открывается нормально всё, но если зайти через http вместо редиректа открывается
страница
с ошибкой... попробовал два варианта, но ничего не срабатывает
Что я делаю не так?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

############################################################################
#### Убираем повторяющиеся слеши (/) в URL ####
############################################################################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
#Проверяем, повторяется ли слеш (//) более двух раз.
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
#Исключаем все лишние слеши.
# Вариант 1
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.local-host\/$1.ru [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.local-host.ru/$1 [R=301]
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.local-host.ru/$1 [R=301]

# Вариант 2
#RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
# RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /errdoc.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: Php код можете использовать на сайте?

Comment: Да, пытался использовать php (header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://redirect2.php');), но тоже не работает.